# A book of wheels

Tags: reference-request

I heard that exist a branch of mathematics called wheel theory that extends the concept of commutative ring, and in it can be defined "division by zero", I want to read about this stuff, but I can't found any reference, so, anyone of you know a book about this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory (see reference)

Comment: @Amzoti there are other books?

Comment: Not that I know about, but perhaps there are sections within a book, but I am not aware of any either. the paper by Carlstrom is very nice and detailed. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome! Enjoy! De nada!

Comment: Did it not occur to you to google "wheel division by zero"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Wheels - On Division by Zero Jesper Carlstrom*](http://www2.math.su.se/reports/2001/11/2001-11.pdf)

I am not sure if there is a book on it.

Comment: I'll have to bookmark this!

Comment: I am surprised to not not find more on the topic!