# What is the meaning of $\frac{0}{0}$?

Tags: calculus

I asked my teacher what is the real meaning of $\cfrac{0}{0}$, and the answer I got was "nobody knows".
I can't leave this subject "as is". I need a decent explanation, at least an explanation to why "nobody knows". I'm sure you'll come up with a few good answers.

Comment: These might be interesting to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332520/a-book-of-wheels, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144715/will-division-by-zero-be-defined-eventually, ...

Comment: Am I right when I say $\frac 0{0} = \frac0{1} * \frac1{0}$  and because $\frac1{0}$ is not defined, you cannot do the multiplication, so it is undefined?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/488920) might also be of interest.

Comment: @zerosofthezeta Neither side of your equation is defined, which makes it meaningless.  But you are right that $0/0$ being undefined is related to $1/0$ being undefined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I really hope your calculus teacher didn't say "nobody knows": $\frac{0}{0}$ is pretty well understood. It's just that it's undefined (without further context).

What I mean by "context" is: it's possible to give meaning to limits of the form $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
where $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$, but this depends on your choice of $f$ and $g$. For instance
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1, \qquad \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{kx}-1}{x} = k, \quad \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x}{x^3} = \infty, \quad \cdots$$
These are all different, despite the fact they're all of the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

So it's not that nobody knows, it's just that it's meaningless! But we *can* assign meaning if we know how the $0$s in the fraction came to be.

Comment: They're only "of the form $0/0$" if we pretend that the limit of the quotient is the quotient of the limits, which it isn't.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Hence "of the form" rather than "equal to". I think this language usage is standard, cf. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: I didn't mean to pick on you, because as you say the language is standard, but in my opinion this standard language is almost as silly as the teacher's saying "nobody knows."  I tried to express this idea better in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The expression $0/0$ is meaningless because the operation of division $(a,b) \mapsto a/b$ is not defined for pairs $(a,b)$ where $b$ is zero, just as it is not defined for pairs $(a,b)$ where $b$ is an elephant.

Sometimes you will hear that $0/0$ is an "indeterminate form" that can equal different things depending on the context.  This is a horribly imprecise way of speaking.  What it really means is that if you are evaluating a limit and you do the computation

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0}  f(x)}{\lim_{x \to 0}  g(x)} = \frac{0}{0}$$

Then you have made a mistake in the first step and you have to evaluate the limit in a different way, *e.g.* with l'Hospital's rule, to get a valid answer (which could be anything depending on the particulars of the problem, hence "indeterminate.")  This reason that the first step in the displayed calculation is a mistake is that the rule "the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits" is not true in general—it is only true when the limit of the denominator is nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

Math is logic.

$12/3=4$ because if you have twelve oranges and three kids, each gets four.

However, dividing by zero is *illogical*; what does it mean? It is no longer a math question, but a philosophical one.

Everything you do in math needs to make sense!

Comment: Exactly. So when I divide nothing to no one (as giving no-apples to nobody) is like I'm doing something (or nothing) infinitely. And as much as it doesn't make any sense, it kinda sounds like something that happens all the time.

Comment: I resent the implication that philosophy is not logical.

Comment: Correction: math is applied logic, in the same way physics is applied math, chemistry is applied physics, biology is applied chemistry...it goes on forever..!

Comment: Some infinities being larger than others also doesn't make sense, yet is accepted as math.

Comment: Does taking the square root of $-1$ make sense in terms of oranges?

Comment: Yes, but you woll not survive the ensuing release of energy. A negative orange (a structure such that putting it with another orange causes both to disappear), must necessarily be made out of antimatter. Putting a piece of antimatter with a piece of antimatter, each being the size of an orange (0.4 kg total), will release $3.6\times10^{16}$ Joules, which is about 3 times the annual energy consumption of the entire country of Mongolia. Released in a matter of microseconds, the ensuing blast would remove the experimenter (as well as anyone in the area) from the gene pool immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if $0/0$ is well-defined then it should play nicely with our definition of division. Specifically, $a/b = c$ if $a = cb$. So there's gotta be some c such that $0c = 0$. Let's try 1. $0\cdot 1 = 0$, so $0/0 = 1$.

Not too bad. Now let's try two. $0\cdot 2 = 0$, so $0/0 = 2$. Since equality is transitive, $1=2$.

Aaaaaand we just broke math. We resolve this by saying that $0/0$ is not defined, which keeps everything running nicely with a minimum of fuss.