# Why does $0/0$ have to be undefined?

Tags: definition

Why can't it no be $\pm$ Infinity?

If $x/1$ is $x$ then $x/0$ should be $\pm$ Infinity.

Comment: Down vote cause you dont know?

Comment: You cannot divide by zero. Zero does not have a multiplicative inverse in the field of rational numbers (or real numbers, or complex numbers, or any field), because the existence of such an inverse would be inconsistent with the field axioms.

Comment: Did you check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556957/why-not-define-0-0-to-be-0 ?

Comment: @Paulistic ..Kind of like infinity?

Comment: Other question does not answer why you cant use +- Infinity instead of undefined

Comment: the expression $\frac{a}{b}$ is only shorthand for the formal expression $ab^{−1}$, where $b^{−1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$. Since the field axioms only guarantee the existence of such inverses for nonzero elements, this expression has no meaning when $b$ is zero. As @jonnytan999 stated in his answer, $\frac{0}{0}$ could be anything..... But Just not with the axioms for maths we have today.

Answer (score 2):

If x/y=z, z*y=x.
Agree? 
For 0/0, we have z*0=0. z can be any number, thus 0/0 can be anything.

Comment: exactly.. thus not knowing what anything is, this would make it infinity  + or -  of course